# Tried to make a variable that's a random number but got an error. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: java, random

I want to create a random int value ranging from 1-3. I researched and wrote this:

```
@Override
Random rand = new Random();
n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
public int quantityDropped(Random par1Random) {
    return n;
}
```

So it said my code had errors and it didn't specify. I can't find the error myself, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you writing Javascript or Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, it says that the `Random.nextInt` method call returns "a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)".

To get a random number between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (inclusive) in Java, you do this:

```
Random r = new Random():
int randomNum = random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

As such, to get a random number from 1-3 (both inclusive), do this:

```
Random r = new Random():
int randomNum = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use:

```
parseInt(Math.random() * 4)
```

Comment: I believe the question is tagged incorrectly as Javascript when it should be Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration syntax is incorrect.

At the simplest, the method could look like this:

```
public int quantityDropped() {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
}
```

`ThreadLocalRandom` extends `Random` with some helpful methods, like generating an `int` in a (half-open) range.

If `quantityDropped()` is intended to override a method of a parent class, or implement an abstract method declaration in a parent type, you should add the `@Override` annotation.

If you intended to pass a random number generator to the method for some reason (for example, you want to explicitly seed the generator to produce a consistent sequence for testing), the method could look like this:

```
public int quantityDropped(Random random) {
    return random.nextInt(2) + 1;
}
```

Again, add the `@Override` annotation if appropriate.

However, I doubt that's a good design for a class. If you are trying to create a mock implementation of some type that uses random numbers to imitate a real component, consider storing the `Random` instance in a field of that object:

```
class MockQuantityDropper implements QuantityDropper {

    private final Random random;
    MockQuantityDropper(Random random) { this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random); }

    @Override
    public int quantityDropped() {
        return random.nextInt(3) + 1;
    }

}
```